# How much clock drift is considered normal for a non-networked windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, date-time

I have a stand-alone PC with no network connection running Windows 7 (64bit) and the system clock loses about 1 minute per week. Is this level of drift considered "normal" or is it a dodgy RTC or a Windows configuration issue or something else?

What is the expected accuracy (roughly) of a PC clock?

EDIT: The PC is never switched off.

Comment: Is the system on most of the time, all of the time, or what? It does matter, because the RTC in most systems is much less accurate when running on battery.

Comment: In my experience, computer's RTC usually have a high clock drift. And I think it has to do with poor RTC quality. How much drift can be considered normal is difficult to say. I think it's better asking how much drift are you willing to accept.

Comment: It is something else, namely the ambiguous quality of the 32768 Hz oscillator that drives the RTC. Among several PCs I've seem Windows system time drift between +1 to -1 minute per week.

Comment: Anecdotal: My work desktop drifts by around 8 seconds/day without NTP (cheap-ish motherboard). My home desktop drifts around 1-2 seconds/week (top of the line gaming motherboard). Both are on 24x7. No idea if there's a general correlation between drift and motherboard quality.

Comment: Data points: One of my ~7 year old dual-socket servers has 7.513 ppm clock drift compared to a stratum 1 NTP server in the same data center. That's **1 second every 1.5 days(!)** Another server located inside the same 4-node chassis as that one has 2.299 ppm drift (1 second every 5 days) compared to the same NTP server. Both numbers are far higher than I naively expected and makes one-way latency measurements hard.

Answer (score 5):

I would also like to know what is the typical ("expected") clock drift of standard RTCs found in common PC hardware. The NTP FAQ from www.ntp.org provides some information on the topic:

- [3.3.1.1. How bad is a Frequency Error of 500 PPM?](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-sw-clocks-quality.htm#AEN1220) says that a 500 PPM error corresponds to a drift of 43 seconds per day, and "Only poor old mechanical wristwatches are worse."
- From [3.3.1.2. What is the Frequency Error of a good Clock?](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-sw-clocks-quality.htm#AEN1230):

  > I'm not sure, but but I think a chronometer is allowed to drift mostly by six seconds a day when the temperature doesn't change by more than 15° Celsius from room temperature. That corresponds to a frequency error of 69 PPM.
  >
  > I read about a temperature compensated quartz that should guarantee a clock error of less than 15 seconds per year, but I think they were actually talking about the frequency variation instead of absolute frequency error. In any case that would be 0.47 PPM. As I actually own a wrist watch that should include that quartz, I can state that the absolute frequency error is about 2.78 PPM, or 6 seconds in 25 days.
  >
  > For the Meinberg GPS 167 the frequency error of the free running oven-controlled quartz is specified as 0.5 PPM after one year, or 43 milliseconds per day (roughly 16 seconds per year)
- [8.3.1.1.1. How accurate is the CMOS clock?](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-trbl-spec.htm#AEN5674) mentions (typical?) frequency errors in the range of 12 to 17 PPM for one specific machine.

Comment: Midrange laptop from 2018 hadn't been syncing for 41 days minus two hours, the clock was off by ~31 seconds (power-on time will have been a fraction of the total time that passed, maybe average 2-3 hours per day). That's a bit higher than the last bullet point but in the same ballpark, using the conversion you gave above of 2.78PPM = 6s per 25d and assuming it's linear. Temperature will definitely have been variable as I took it on a weekend trip, plus the on/standby cycles

Answer (score 2):

Most of my machines are around 20 ppm off, which is about 12 seconds per week. So you're seeing about 5 times the average. That's unusually high, but not so high that it means something is necessarily wrong.